# Express not sending response to ajax post or get

Tags: node.js, express

I have some front end code that looks like:

```
$.ajax({
    url:target,
    data: zform.serialize(),
    dataTyp:'json',
    type:'POST',
    success:function(data, status, jqXHR) {

       $(".target", source).html(data.widget.url);

       source.find('.edit').hide()
       source.find('.saved').show();
    },
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        alert(textStatus);
    });
```

This finds my form, serializes it, and sends it to the server at the desired URL.  This works fine and the node.js server receives it.

Then in a request handler for node:

```
m.Target.find({where:{id:linkId, UserId:req.user.id}}).success(function(target){
            target.updateAttributes({target:url}).success(function(target){

                try{
                var response={status:"updated",
                           widget:{url:target.url}
                        };
                res.send(response);
                res.end();
                console.log("sent");
                }catch(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        });
```

The variables come in just fine, the DB gets updated via sequelize just fine, and the success method is called.  But the client never gets the response.  It just sits in pending status.
I've tried doing this as both a GET and  POST, and I've tried res.json, res.send, and res.write.  Nothing has worked and I am very confused.

Comment: We nneed more then just your database query to figure out why express doesn't work.

Comment: why the `try..catch` is there? maybe it throws an error and possibly logs it but doesn't end the request. Also try add a plain `return;` after `res.end()` sometimes it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, but I don't know if this is what caused it.

1. I had a typo in the original request for dataType:json
2. changed my way of responding to this:

> ```
>  res.status(201).type('JSON');
>     res.write(JSON.stringify({widget:{
>             url: target.dataValues.target,
>           startLvl: target.dataValues.startLvl,
>           endLvl: target.dataValues.endLvl,
>           id: target.dataValues.id
>       }
>      }));
>      res.end(
> ```

);